# How do I make a function be ran by a sensor/turtle give priority to sensors/turtles with the current highest energy first? Netlogo

Tags: networking, netlogo, agent, agent-based-modeling, energy

this if my first time putting up a question here so I'm not too sure if I'm doing this right but here goes.
I'm currently working on a project wherein I deploy sensors and each sensor is given an amount of energy and a flood will be started from a random point. Each time a sensor forwards this function its energy decreases. The stop criteria is set to be that if any sensor gets to 0 energy, then the whole process will stop.

I'm trying to create an algorithm so that a sensor will try and ask other sensors within its radius to try and flood other sensors with higher energy first. The idea is to make the whole thing more energy efficient and to delay a sensor from getting to 0 energy as much as possible or to spread the flood around the map as efficiently as possible.

Here is my code so far:

```
breed [sensor a-sensor]
globals [packets-sent packets-rcv coverage-avg]
sensor-own [energy]

;; this procedures sets up the model
to setup
  clear-all

  set packets-sent 0
  set packets-rcv 0

  ask patches [  ;; color the world  green
    set pcolor black
  ]

  create-sensor num-nodes - 1 [  ;; create the initial sheep
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color white
    set shape "circle"
    set energy initial-energy
  ]
  create-sensor 1 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color blue
    set shape "circle"
    set energy initial-energy
  ]

  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask sensor with [color = blue and energy <= initial-energy] [
    ask sensor in-radius communication-range with [color != blue] [
      let d distance myself  ;;this is me just messing around, dunno how close this is to my actual goal
      let p (initial-energy - d) / energy ;; I'd assume the algorithm would go here???
      if random 100 < 100 * p [ ;; again, just messing around
        set color blue
        set packets-rcv packets-rcv + 1
        set energy energy - 1
      ]
    ]
    set color yellow
    set packets-sent packets-sent + 1

    

  ]

    


  set coverage-avg 100 * (count sensor with [color = blue] + count sensor with [color = yellow]) / num-nodes
  if not any? sensor with [color = yellow] [stop]
  if any? sensor with [energy = 0] [stop]
  if not any? sensor with [color = white] [stop]
  if not any? sensor with [color = blue] [stop]
  tick
end
```

[this is what my interface looks like so far as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJzX2.png)

Thanks in advance for any help provided!